# Change height automaticly on main page with no scroll, with a fixed nav and footer

Tags: html, css

This project, is for mobile usage.

There is a fixed nav that is working fine.

And a fixed div at the footer with some icons. (Working fine as well)

I need the content in between the nav and the fixed div at the footer, to fill the height content automaticly, **without the scroll**.

So when the device changes the height the content will auto complete the height as well.

Right now, if I change device the device height, it leaves a blank on the bottom.

I've tried changing min-height, max-height, positions, and still no luck.

I'll try to show some code here, but it's hard, because I use many libraries and lot's of css, including boostrap.

But you can test the project here:
http://www.neevasoft.com/mobi/

Here is the Menu

```
<body data-open="click" data-menu="vertical-overlay-menu" data-col="2-columns" class="vertical-layout vertical-overlay-menu 2-columns   menu-expanded fixed-navbar">

<!-- fixed-top-->
<nav class="header-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-with-menu fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-shadow navbar-brand-center">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item mobile-menu d-md-none mr-auto">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                        <h2 class="brand-text"> 
                            <span> Jorge<i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="notify"> <span class="heartbit">
</span> <span class="point"></span> </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-container content">
            <div id="navbar-mobile" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto float-left">
                    <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-menu-main menu-toggle hidden-xs">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<!-- main menu-->
<div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-light menu-accordion menu-shadow menu-border">
    <div class="main-menu-content">
        <ul id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation" class="navigation navigation-main">
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Invista</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="menu-item">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="menu-item">Homebroker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="menu-item">Gráfico Avançado</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Resumo</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Posição Consolidada</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Posição Operacional</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Vencimentos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Relatório de Performance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="menu-item">Desenquadramentos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Ordem</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Ordens do dia</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Negócios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Calls</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-clone"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Posição</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Bovespa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Títulos Públicos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">BM&F</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Garantias</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Proventos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Renda Fixa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Clubes e Fundos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Nota de Corretagem</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Bovespa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">BM&F</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Saldo Extrato</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Saldos e Projeções</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Extratos de C/C</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item open">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Clientes</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="menu-content">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Dados Cadastrais</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Perfil do Investidor</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Informe de Rendimentos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Rendimentos Tesouro Direto</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Termo de adesão</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Limite para Operar BM&F</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Monitoramento de Prejuizo BM&F</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
         <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Atendimento Online</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
                    <span data-i18n="" class="menu-title">Sair</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the main page (Between nav and footer div)

```
<!-- Main Content-->
<div class="app-content content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-body">

            <div class="row match-height">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content collapse show">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <canvas id="column-multi-axis" height="200"></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div id="goal-list-scroll" class="table-responsive position-relative">
                            <table class="table mb-0">

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#007aba">Ações</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#007aba">$0.18</font>
                                        </td>


                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#b8b828">Opções</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#b8b828">$0.12</font>
                                        </td>


                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#aa2524">Termo</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#aa2524">$220</font>
                                        </td>


                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#00b1b1">BM&F</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#00b1b1">$880</font>
                                        </td>


                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#c75fc7">Garantias</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#c75fc7">$1002</font>
                                        </td>


                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#1fc11e">Tesouro Direto</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#1fc11e">$1200</font>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#b44013">Financeiro</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#b44013">$1200</font>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#461577">BTC</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#461577">$1200</font>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#762100">Renda Fixa</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#762100">$1200</font>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#5599ff">Clubes e Fundos</font>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <font color="#5599ff">$1200</font>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the footer div

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row2">


                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="float-md-left d-block d-md-inline-block">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/invista.png">
                            Invista
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="float-md-right d-block d-md-inline-blockd-none d-lg-block">
                            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square2"></span>
                                Resumo
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <span class="float-md-right d-block d-md-inline-blockd-none d-lg-block">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop2"></i>
                                Ordem
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The css I believe that is relevant:

```
html body .content.app-content {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 89%;
}
html body .content.app-content {
overflow: hidden;
}
.vertical-overlay-menu .content {
margin-right: 0;
}
html body .content {
padding: 0;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
-o-transition: 300ms ease all;
-moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
transition: 300ms ease all;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
*, ::before, ::after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html body .content .content-wrapper {
padding: 0rem !important;
max-height: 89%;
}
.content-body {
max-height: 89%;
}
.row {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
}
.card {
margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 40px 0 rgba(62, 57, 107, 0.07), 0 2px 9px 0 rgba(62, 57, 107, 0.06);
box-shadow: 0 10px 40px 0 rgba(62, 57, 107, 0.07), 0 2px 9px 0 rgba(62, 57, 107, 0.06);
}
.card {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
min-width: 0;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
background-clip: border-box;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: In mobile when set to landscape I cannot scroll when the content is cut, it that on propose?

Comment: No, it's not on purpose, I haven't noticed. But we r going to compilate on phonegap. Then I'm not sure if it rotates when it's used as an app.

Comment: Well you can force to not rotate, by default it rotates.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that will be only on portrait. Thanks for checking that out for me.

Answer (score 0):

> try set `content` to

```
min-height:calc(100%);
```

or you can use viewport height like

`min-height:<value>vh;`